# How to create websocket connection between two Docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-network

I've got two Docker containers that need to have a websocket connection between the two.

I run one container like this:

```
docker run --name comm -p 8080:8080 comm_module:latest
```

to expose port 8080 to the host. Then I try to  run the second container like this:

```
docker run --name test -p 8080:8080 datalogger:latest
```

However, I get the error below:

> docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external
>   connectivity on endpoint test
>   (f06588ee059e2c4be981e3676d7e05b374b42a8491f9f45be27da55248189556):
>   Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080 failed: port is already allocated. ERRO[0000]
>   error waiting for container: context canceled

I'm not sure what to do. Should I connect these to a network? How do I run these containers?

Comment: Docker's [Use bridge networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) documentation is a useful starting point.  In that page's terminology you want a "user-defined bridge".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally worked it out. These are the steps involved for a two-way websocket communication between two Docker containers:

1. Modify the source code in the containers to use the name of the other container as the destination host address + port number (e.g. `comm:port_no` inside `test`, and vice versa).
2. Expose the same port (8080) in the Dockerfiles of the two containers and build the images. No need to publish them as they are will be visible to other containers on the network.
3. Create a user-defined bridge network like this:

   `docker network create my-net`
4. Create my first container and attach it to the network:

   `docker create --name comm --network my-net comm_module:latest`
5. Create my second container and attach it to the network:

   `docker create --name test --network my-net  datalogger:latest`
6. Start both containers by issuing the docker start command.

And the two-way websocket communication works nicely!

Answer (score 3):

you can't bind the same host port twice in the same time you may change one of the ports on one container:

```
 docker run --name comm -p 8080:8080 comm_module:latest
 docker run --name test -p 8081:8080 datalogger:latest
```

you may check the configuration in the containers on how they communicate .

you can also create link between them:

```
docker run --name test -p 8081:8080 --link comm datalogger:latest
```

Comment: `--link` hasn't been a preferred approach to this for quite a while now.  If you `docker create network something` and run both containers with `--net something`, they can use each other's `--name` as hostnames (and the container-internal port 8080, not any published port number).

Comment: yes , you are right, I wrote that only for demonestration how thats work

Comment: @LinSel I tried docker run --name test -p 8081:8080 --link comm datalogger:latest but that didn't work. There needs to be a websocket connection on the SAME port between two containers. It can't be a different port number. I tried attaching them both to a network too, but the message isn't reaching the comm_module container.

Comment: you must connect from `test` using `comm:8080` not IPs,localhost  or something else

Comment: Thanks. That works! Now I'm figuring out how to do via a bridged network.

Comment: @LinSel To send messages the other way from comm to datalogger should I use hostname datalogger? I tried that but nothing is coming through.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution works fine.

```
docker network create mynet  
docker run -p 443:443 --net=mynet --ip=172.18.0.3 --hostname=frontend.foobar.com foobarfrontend
docker run -p 9999:9999 --net=mynet --ip=172.18.0.2 --hostname=backend.foobar.com foobarbackend

route /P add 172.18.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0 10.0.75.2
```

the foobarfrontend calls a wss websocket on foobarbackend on port 9999
PS: i work on docker windows 10 with linuxcontainers
have fun